# jQuery DataTables inserting extra double quote

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables to display a table, where each row is a link which calls a jQuery method.  Here's the code which I use to populate the DataTable.

```
table = $("#search-results").DataTable({
   "data": dataTableRows,
   "columns": dataTableColumns,
   "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": "_all",
      "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
         if (type === 'display') {
            var rowValue = rowValues[meta.row];
            data = '<a href=javascript:void(0) OnClick=resultSelected("' + $('#source-control-name').val() + '","' + rowValue + '")>' + data + '</a>';
            alert(data);
         }
         return data;
      }
   }]
});
```

I'm showing a list of my ASP Identity roles, some of which have spaces.  When the user clicks a role, I want to call `resultSelected` and pass the name of the role (which will be in `rowValue` in the code below).  If the role is one word, this works.  However, if the role contains a space, DataTables is inserting an extra double quote.

For instance, if the role name is `Inventory Manager`, the resulting table [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Uwm.jpg) (notice the extra double quote between the words *Inventory* and *manager* in the `resultSelected` call.

I've done an `alert` to print the value of `rowValue` during the rendering function, and `rowValue` doesn't have an extra quote in it, so DataTables must be adding the extra quote.

How do I stop DataTables from adding the extra quote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
data = '<a href=javascript:void(0) OnClick=resultSelected("' + $('#source-control-name').val() + '","' + rowValue + '")>' + data + '</a>';
```

You can change with:

```
data = '<a href=javascript:void(0) OnClick="resultSelected(\'' + $('#source-control-name').val() + '\',\'' + rowValue + '\')">' + data + '</a>';
                                                          ^^^^.....
```

You need to escape the string delimiters.

A demo:

```js
function resultSelected(name, val) {
    console.log('Name: ' + name + ' Value: ' + val);
}

var dataTableRows = [
    {
        "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
        "position":   "System Architect",
        "salary":     "$3,120",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office":     "Edinburgh",
        "extn":       5421
    },
    {
        "name": "Garrett Winters",
        "position": "Director",
        "salary": "5300",
        "start_date": "2011/07/25",
        "office": "Edinburgh",
        "extn": "8422"
    },
];


var dataTableColumns = [
    { "data": "name" },
    { "data": "position" },
    { "data": "office" },
    { "data": "extn" },
    { "data": "start_date" },
    { "data": "salary" }
];
table = $("#search-results").DataTable({
    "data": dataTableRows,
    "columns": dataTableColumns,
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": "_all",
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
            if (type === 'display') {
                var rowValue = row.name;
                data = '<a href=javascript:void(0) OnClick="resultSelected(\''
                        + $('#source-control-name').val() + '\',\'' + rowValue + '\')">' + data + '</a>';
            }
            return data;
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="search-results" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```